# How to move a file in Windows without changing the destination parent folder's modification time (Win32)?

Tags: windows, file-io, last-modified

It appears that when you move / copy a file from some source folder to some destination folder, Windows tends to change the **parent folder's** modification time.

For a copy, it changes the destination's parent folder modification time to now.

For a move, it looks like it changes both the source's parent folder and the destination's parent folder modification time to now.

This is on NTFS.

I presume this is because NTFS is updating the directory index entries in the folder's metadata.

How would you copy or move a file in Windows **without changing the source / destination parent folder's modification time**, using the Win32 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should allow you to put the modification time back the way you found it.  You could use transactions if necessary to avoid the risk of overlapping changes messing this up.

However, I believe you can only change the timestamps on a directory if you have SE_RESTORE privilege enabled, so you'd need to be running as an administrator.  (NOTE: this is *not* because you need to specify FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS to CreateFile in order to get a directory handle; you can do that without special privileges.)

It would probably make more sense to address the problem at the other end, i.e., to fix whatever code or procedure is getting upset by the modification time changing.  After all, the modification time of a folder *should* change when the content of the folder is changed - that's what it's there for!